# mysql multiple foreign key vs inner join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, foreign-keys

Is there any sense in using two foreign key to the same parent table, to avoid inner join?

table: user_profile

```
id1, userid, username, firstname
```

table: user_hobby1

```
id2, userid(fk), hobby, movies
```

table: user_hobby2

```
id3, userid(fk), firstname(fk), hobby, movies
```

I want to select all firstname and hobby from the above table. I am not sure if user_hobby1 or user_hobby2 is the best design in terms of performance? One adds extra foreign key and another requires join.

Query1 :

```
Select firstname, hobby 
from user_hobby2;
```

Query2 :

```
Select p.firstname, h.hobby
from 
 user_profile p
 inner join user_hobby1 h on u.userid=h.userid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the value of an attribute from the user table into the hobby table isn't a "foreign key", that's redundancy.

Our performance objectives are not usually met with an approach of avoiding JOIN operations, which are a normal part of how relational databases operate.

I'd go with the normalized design as a first cut. Each attribute should be dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key. The "firstname" attribute is dependent on the id of the user, not the hobby.

Sometimes, we do gain performance benefits by introducing redundancy into the database. We have to do that in a controlled way, and make sure that we don't get update anomalies. (Consider what changes we want to apply if the value of "firstname" attribute is updated... do we make that change to the user table, the user_hobby table, or both.

Likely, "firstname" is *not* unique in the user table, so we definitely don't want a foreign key referencing that column; we want foreign keys that reference the user table to reference the PRIMARY KEY of the table.

There's no point in having two foreign keys defined between user_hobby and user, if a user_hobby is related to exactly one user. We only need one foreign key... we just store the id from the user table in the user_hobby table.

Answer (score 0):

if you have two FK in user_hobby2 then you can only ensure that userid and username exist in user_profile, but you have no way to ensure which userid goes with a given username.

if you make (userid, username) a composite FK, then you'll guarantee the consistency of each tuple, but composite FK are generally more complicate to deal with. Depending on the behavior for update and delete cascades I've seen mysql triggering them both and refusing to delete from the parent.

Besides... what's the point of keeping that composite FK? It will only help you when you update or delete from user_profile, but won't help you copy the data when you insert new users or new hobbies for a user.

The join you are trying to avoid is very cheap. Just go with the first approach. It's easier to maintain and will help you keep your data consistent and normalized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful, and I will follow your advice.